# Typical impedance values for a large 150 MVA power transformer

Tags: transformer, impedance

I am trying to calculate the impedance in ohms for a 220kV/110kV 150MVA transformer (European grid), but the values I am getting are not in range of values I usually see in online examples.

X in p.u. is 0.06 p.u., so I used:

$$\begin{align*}
Z_{B220} = \frac{V_b*V_b}{S} &= \frac{220\cdot220}{150}\approx322.6 \\
\\
X_{220} &= 0.06\cdot322.6 = 19.3
\end{align*}$$

Does this look like a reasonable value? Secondary side (150kV) would yield ~5 ohm using these formulas.

The reason why I am not sure is that I found some examples online which usually had much smaller values, so I am not sure if I am using p.u. values properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are correct. Your calculated the base impedance of the system for a given voltage and power (220kV, 150MVA) and then applied the impedance of the transformer nameplate in p.u. (0.06 or 6%).

Maybe you saw smaller values in literature due to the specific examples you took (lower voltages and lower power ratings). Those 19.3 ohm would be a very high resistance for a LV (<1.1kV) system.

Answer (score 0):

Short circuit impedance of real transformers (220 kV, 66 kV and 30.8 kV) I can look in my company are between 3% and 8%, 4% is the most common value.

Answer (score -1):

I am not a power system engineer, I'm not familiar with PU (per unit) calculations and my original answer was incorrect so I did some reading.

- [Transformer nameplate impedance:
  Per unit or absolute?](https://www.eaton.com/ecm/groups/public/@pub/@electrical/documents/content/wp009001en.pdf) by Eaton.
- [Per-unit system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Per-unit_system) on Wikipedia.

---

The equipment in question is specified as:

> 220 kV / 110 kV, 150 MVA

What appears to be missing is the *V<sub>base</sub>* and *P<sub>base</sub>* assumptions which, in this example appear to be \$ V_{base} = 1\ \text {kV} = 1 \ \text {PU} \$ and \$ P_{base} = 1\ \text {MVA} = 1 \ \text {PU} \$. If this is correct then the mixing of kV and MVA in the equation becomes acceptable and your calculations look correct.

But what do I know?

Comment: But the nominator is kV squared, i.e. if I used volts and watts, I would just have a factor of million in both the nom. and the denominator.

Comment: Don't worry about the numbers. Worry about the units and the numbers will look after themselves. It's just a variation of \$ Z = \frac {V^2} P \$. The units work out as \$ \frac {V^2} W = \frac {V^2} {VI} = \frac V I = \Omega \$. Try it!

Comment: Zbase is KV (line-line) squared divided by MVA (3 ph).  220 x 220 / 150 is correct.  Yes, your result looks correct.

Comment: I don't work with HV networks other than a 10 kV supply to a plant so I'm not going to be too reliable. What are the units for Zbase then? It looks like milliohms to me.

Comment: Hi Transistor - units are ohms.